# Python "in" does not check for type?

Tags: python, unit-testing, types, boolean, identity

```
>>> False in [0]
True
>>> type(False) == type(0)
False
```

The reason I stumbled upon this:

For my unit-testing I created lists of valid and invalid example values for each of my types. (with 'my types' I mean, they are not 100% equal to the python types)
So I want to iterate the list of all values and expect them to pass if they are in my valid values, and on the other hand, fail if they are not.
That does not work so well now:

```
>>> valid_values = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> invalid_values = [True, False, "foo"]
>>> for value in valid_values + invalid_values:
...     if value in valid_values:
...         print 'valid value:', value
... 
valid value: -1
valid value: 0
valid value: 1
valid value: 2
valid value: 3
valid value: True
valid value: False
```

Of course I disagree with the last two 'valid' values.

Does this mean I really have to iterate through my valid_values and compare the type?

Comment: +1 Hmm, I never though that python's `in` does not check for type. Very interesting . . .

Comment: @BenJames, hmm, I wonder how would it would break the duck typing in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have written, the "in" code does not do what you want it to do. You'll need something else.

If you really want a type check (where the check is for exactly the same type) then you can include the type in the list:

```
>>> valid_values = [(int, i) for i in [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>> invalid_values = [True, False, "foo"]
>>> for value in [v[1] for v in valid_values] + invalid_values:
...   if (type(value), value) in valid_values:
...     print value, "is valid"
...   else:
...     print value, "is invalid"
... 
-1 is valid
0 is valid
1 is valid
2 is valid
3 is valid
True is invalid
False is invalid
foo is invalid
>>>
```

Handling subtypes is a bit more difficult, and will depend on what you want to do.

Comment: I used your solution to prevent the additional loop.
But I changed it to:
valid_values = [(type(v), v) for v in [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]]

Answer (score 15):

The problem is not the missing type checking, but because in Python `bool` is a subclass of `int`. Try this:

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
```

Comment: I don't complain about False == 0, but only about the fact that "in" will not check for the type.

Comment: `in` returns true if one item in the sequence is `equal` to the requested object. So your problem is not the `in` operator, but the `==` operator.

Comment: I just would like to have a check for identity there. Is there a way to do this without using a loop?

Comment: Oh, I comming from .Net side, I have a notion that `bool` and `int` are under the `object` class. Assuming that `__cmp__` is used in `in` and upon checking, `bool.__cmp__` uses that of `int`. I wonder if `bool` would just override it's own `__cmp__`?

Comment: Just checked [PEP 285, Adding a bool type(under *Specification*)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) and `True + 1 == 2` will work due to backward compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), `__contains__` is done by iterating over the collection and testing elements by `==`. Hence the actual problem is caused by the fact, that `False == 0` is `True`.

Comment: For the pedantic... it checks for a ``__contains__(self,thing)`` method first, *then* falls back to iterating over the object.  For a true ``list``, there is ``__contains__``, thus the fallback.

Comment: @GreggLind you are of course right. However, I could not find a better definition of "in". In order to conform to the principle of least surprise, an overloaded `__contains__` method should do something similar anyway.

Comment: I have had this bite me when determining containment exhausts a generator and/or runs forever.  Avoidable by writing a *smarter* ``__contains__``.  (think of things like ``itertools.cycle``)

Answer (score 3):

Since `True == 1` and `False == 0` it's hard to differentiate between the two.

One possible but ugly approach (which is also not guaranteed to work in all Python implementations but should be OK in CPython):

```
>>> for value in valid_values + invalid_values:
...    if value in valid_values and not any(v is value for v in invalid_values):
...        print ('valid value:', value)
...
valid value: -1
valid value: 0
valid value: 1
valid value: 2
valid value: 3
```

Comment: I would have liked to prevent another loop. Since this check will be executed quite often during most of my tests.